# Detect if cookies are enabled in the browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

The code below works in all current browser except for IE.  In IE the message doesn't display.

```
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled == 0) {
    document.write("Cookies are not enabled.");
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I can do to make the above code work in IE 10 & 11?

I've tried code that works in IE but then it works in most browser except for Safari.   Here's the code.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    if(/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent))
        var cookies = ("cookie" in document && (document.cookie.length > 0 ||
        (document.cookie = "test").indexOf.call(document.cookie, "test") > -1));
    document.write(cookies ? "" : "Cookies are not enabled.");
</script>
```

But this still displays for FF, Safari, and Chrome.  So then I have two messages displaying....

Comment: Your code isn't working because the property `navigator.cookieEnabled` returns only `true` or `false`. Try this instead; `if(navigator.cookieEnabled){/*enabled*/}else{/*disabled*/}`. It seems to work in IE 11 in Windows 10.

Comment: `navigator.cookieEnabled` should be supported for IE6+. Exactly what trouble are you having with it?

Comment: @www139 `false == 0` is valid JS, and should not be the reason why this code is not working. That being said, @user5319102, it is pretty silly to have that unnecessary equality check in there.

Comment: @Hamms the message doesn't display in IE only.

Comment: and are you sure that cookies are in fact disabled in your test browser? What happens if you `console.log` the message rather than attempting to write it to the document?

Comment: Yes cookies are disabled.  And they are disabled in my other browsers too and the message displays.  Except for IE.

Comment: console.log doesn't display it either in IE.

Comment: @user5319102 I tested your first block of code in IE 11 (in Windows 10) and it seems to work. Check any other code dependencies to make sure you haven't broke your code. Check any events linked to the execution of this code block. For things like this, a simple alert box might make the test result more obvious. Also add an else condition so that you know the code is running.

Comment: @Hamms I now understand the OPs condition. I was confused since I've never seen a condition used in such a way. I've never had a need to use numeral conditions to check a Boolean condition. Thank you for explaining :) .

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var event = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
 if (!trySetCookie()) {
  // cookies are disabled
 }
 else{
 // cookies are enabled
 }
}
function trySetCookie() {
 setCookie("testCookie", "testValue", 1);
 var cookieValue = getCookie("testCookie");
 if (cookieValue == "" || cookieValue == null)
    return false;
 return true;
}
// set a test cookie in the user's browser
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
 document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
// read the test cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
 var name = cname + "=";
 var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
 var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
 for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
 }
 return "";
}
```

["$(document).ready()" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top)