# Turning cookies on in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, cookies, browser

I want to make it so if the user has cookies disabled, a prompt is displayed which has a switch which allows them to turn them on. Is there anyway to do this in the browser? Or do modern browsers disallow this kind of behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824377/detect-if-cookies-are-enabled-in-the-browser

Comment: I know how to detect if cookies exist. I want to know if it is possible to turn them on from within the application or as a JS prompt.

Comment: You definitely can't. It's a security thing.

Comment: If the site could turn them back on, what would be the point of turning them off?